# PHP Mailer languages encoding issues: It accepts only English

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am using php mailer at my website contact form. When i receive a message in greek language, i don't receive the text as typed in the contact form. In class.phpmailer.php file line 59 the encoding is   `public $CharSet  = 'iso-8859-1';` Is there a way to make my text appear correctly as typed in the contact form?

> Languages comonly supported by ISO/IEC 8859-1 can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Modern_languages_with_complete_coverage)

**I have also tried german and albanian languages but i also have the same problem. I can only receive english, if the user types another language on some words i receive "chinese".**

[image]

> I get this message:
>   [image]

**The code:**

```
     <?php
        require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

        // if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
        if (empty($_POST['Email'])) {
            $_POST['Email'] = "-";
        }
        if (empty($_POST['Name'])) {
            $_POST['Name'] = "-";
        }
        if (empty($_POST['Subject'])) {
            $_POST['Subject'] = " ";
        }
        if (empty($_POST['message'])) {
            $_POST['message'] = "-";
        }




        $mymail = smtpmailer("example@gmail.com", $_POST['Email'], $_POST['Name'],
 $_POST['Subject'], $_POST['message']);
        function smtpmailer($to, $from, $from_name, $subject, $body)
        {
            $mail = new PHPMailer;
            $mail->isSMTP();
            $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
            $mail->Host        = 'smtp.gmail.com';
            $mail->Port        = 587;
            $mail->SMTPSecure  = 'tls';
            $mail->SMTPAuth    = true;
            $mail->Username    = 'example@gmail.com';
            $mail->Password    = 'pass';
            $mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
            $mail->Subject  = " Contact form ~Name: $from_name ~ subject: $subject  ";
         $mail->Body = " You have received a new message 
          from $from_name, here are the details:\n\n_____
          ___________________\n" . "\nDear $from_name,\n
      Your enquiry had been received on " . date("D j F ") . "
       \nINFORMATION SUBMITTED: " . "\n\nName: $from_name\n\nEmail: $from
        \nSubject: $subject\n\nMessage: $body \n\nTo:
         $to\nDate: " . date("d/m/y") . "\nWebsite: " . "\n____________
        __________________"; //end body


        $mail->AddAddress($to);
        //send the message, check for errors
        if (!$mail->send()) {
          echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;

         } else {
       echo "Well done $from_name, your message has been sent!\n
    We will reply to the following email: $from" . "\nYour Message: $body";
            }




        } //end function smtpmailer
        //}


        ?>
```

Comment: Are greek characters included in iso-8859-1? What if you try UTF8?

Comment: these are the supported languages: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Modern_languages_with_complete_coverage  Greek lang is not supported

Comment: have you tried iconv() function in php??

Comment: One time ago, i have problems with encoding because the file itself was saved in another charset than specified, so for example, I tried to send an UTF8 message from a file saved in an ISO encoding... maybe this is your problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your example output, the char count amplification suggests that you're receiving data from your form in UTF-8, but are then telling PHPMailer (by default) that it's ISO-8859-1, which results in the kind of corruption you're seeing.

You should be using UTF-8 everywhere. In PHPMailer you do it like this:

```
$mail->CharSet  = 'UTF-8';
```

Then you need to be sure that every step of your processing supports UTF-8 as well.

Comment: on what files of php-mailer should i check for this ?

Comment: You don't have to touch PHPMailer's files, just add that line into your own script, in the same place you're setting other PHPMailer properties.

Comment: Also, I can tell you're using an old version of PHPMailer - [get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), or learn how to use composer.

Comment: not really old, just 3-4 months old, i will try to replace my php mailer folder with the newer one and let you know if that fixed the problem

Comment: Just updating it won't fix the problem - you still need to make that change in your own code. Updating will however fix other bugs and security holes that you will otherwise be vulnerable to.

Comment: is my php script safe from hackers? I mean i have my gmail password there and the file is in the root of my website, isn't a way to protect it ?

Comment: It's safe so long as your site never serves PHP as plain text or displays debug output. It's safer to move your credentials to a file outside the web root so it can't be accessed directly, but aside from that, if you need to use credentials, you need them as plain text at some point - this is not a problem unique to PHPMailer. BTW there was an important security release of PHPMailer this weekend, so make sure you're running latest.